# Socket library on python 2.7 and 3.9.12 , ( type error : bytes like object required . )

Tags: python, networking, tcp, udp, python-sockets

I'm following a book ( Black hat python   by     Justin Seitz )

I tried exact same code as the book , and attempted to write a code which will establish a TCP connection (see commented bit of the code)  relying on socket lib .

but it keeps giving me , an error which says :-  Bytes like object is required on line 10 .

not  sure what's the problem is with the 2nd bit (uncommented part of the code )   maybe something IP related

I'm aware that the book is using python 2.7  , but I'm using Python 3.9.12
Is the python version causing the problem ?

If so , what is the 3.9.12 equivalent syntax of these codes ?

tnx in advance

```
import socket

#target_host = "www.google.com"
#target_port = 80

#client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

#response = client.recv(4096)

#print(response)






target_host = 127.0.0.1
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host,target_port))

data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")` to `client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")`. Prefixing a string with `b` creates a [bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).
The problem with the second part is most likely because `127.0.0.1` (localhost) does not have a server running on port 80.